# I am using concurrency 2 for a consumer and creating two instance of the consumer. When I terminate on of the consumer, it is not rebalancing

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Initial scenario:

```
Consumer Group : test-1
Container one consuming partition-1, partition-2
Container two consuming partition-0 

So after some message consumption I am killing Container two. 
It should I ideally rebalance and assign partition-0 to Container one, 
If I am not wrong. 

In my case, Container one keeps consuming partition-1, and partition-2 only. 
Partition-0 is nowhere now. Is there any property I should add for rebalance 
or will it automatically do it?
```

This one is happening when I used functional approach. I checked in one of my earlier project where it is working fine with @StreamListener version.

Comment: Show your config, please, and function.